# Sorting an array of hashes, based on the value of a particular key within each hash in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, hash

I've done some searching and struggled to find the answer to this one.

Say I have an array of hashes like this..

```
my @AoH = (
    {   'ip_type'     => 1,
        'ip_ref'      => 0001,
        'ip_address'  => '192.168.0.1',
        'ip_priority' => '100'
    },
    {   'ip_type'     => 1,
        'ip_ref'      => 0002,
        'ip_address'  => '192.168.0.2',
        'ip_priority' => '1'
    }
);
```

In context, these are multiple IP addresses, in which I intend to load balance across. The 'ip_priority' value dictates which is first, and subsequently which is second in pirority. primary and backup, basically.

However, I want to order the array elements (aka the hashes) numerically based on the ip priority value within the hash.

So, preferably the above AoH would be...

```
my @AoH = (
    {   'ip_type'     => 1,
        'ip_ref'      => 0002,
        'ip_address'  => '192.168.0.2',
        'ip_priority' => '1'
    },
    {   'ip_type'     => 1,
        'ip_ref'      => 0001,
        'ip_address'  => '192.168.0.1',
        'ip_priority' => '100'
    }
);
```

so `$AoH[0]->{ip_priority}` now cotains 1 and `$AoH[1]->{ip_priority}` contains 100.

How can I perform a sort in order to achieve the second example above? im struggling to find a workable example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
my @sorted = sort {$a->{ip_priority} <=> $b->{ip_priority}} @AoH;
```

Comment: achhh...

i tried something just like this. perhaps I had a typo in my one.

Thank you mate, it worked fine.